# How to store .NET Core non-interactive app credentials properly on both Windows and Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, security, .net-core, dpapi

I need to store credentials for my app. I've read it's a very bad practice to store them with code.

I know, DPAPI is just made for it, but how to use it on Linux like Ubuntu?
So - if I could make DPAPI work on Linux without spending whole day on it - it would be my first choice.

Then it's poor man's security - a file on target machine. So - not with the source ;) The file is in a directory only the admin can access, so it's as secure as the host itself. I can also have the file on my Windows development machine, it's as secure as my machine.

Tell me why the file is bad? ;)

Comment: Whose credentials are you storing?  The user's?   Why not store them in ~/.yourapp?  The user has entered them, so they know what they are.   Something that requires access to a server?   Again, if they are user creds, then ~/.  If they are server creds, then who is typing them in?  Does your code require contact with a server?  Then don't store the creds, store a token (with a timeout) that the server has given the client (based on their creds).

Comment: Both. Users and system. My service needs to access the DB, then it has to store users credentials they use for external services. I will store them encrypted in my DB, but again, I need the encryption key stored too. Both on my development machine and on target server. There's a deadline to just start the service, then it can be developed more properly, so I look for a quick way for now, yet not a total security horror.

Comment: Who are you protecting it against? The users or the FBI? Users probably don't care and FBI is probably not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to store credentials for my app.

Mmmhmmm.

> I've read it's a very bad practice to store them with code.

Not "with code", but **in** code: i.e. as string literals baked into your executable.

> I know, DPAPI is just made for it

Yup.

> but how to use it on Linux like Ubuntu?

With difficulty.

> So - if I could make DPAPI work on Linux without spending whole day on it - it would be my first choice.

You can't. DPAPI is a Windows *thang*.

> Then it's poor man's security - a file on target machine. So - not with the source

At least on Linux you can take advantage of the *far simpler* filesystem security model to secure files from access by other users without too much effort (i.e. `chmod`, compared to Windows where you need to faff around with DACLs (caveat: DACLs are still objectively far,far superior to `chmod`. Consider using SELinux to get DACLs outside of Windows).

> The file is in a directory only the admin can access, so it's as secure as the host itself.

Debatable.

> Tell me why the file is bad? ;)

I can't. You haven't told us *anything* about the file.

---

Better solution: take advantage of any available hardware TPM to store encryption keys: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Trusted_Platform_Module

Comment: The file is not very relevant. Just a password or an AES key. It's always a matter of a single secret. The rest can be encrypted and / or kept on AKV.

Comment: @Harry What is "AKV" in this context?

Comment: Azure Key Vault.

Comment: The TPM is the way to go. It's not that easy on .net (but it is possible)